# Replacing input text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I had an input field like so for example:

```
<input id="inputBox" type="text">
```

And the user enters 'abc' for example, how can I change this immediately to '123'?
I want this to happen as soon as soon as the user enters 'abc'.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: bind `onkeyup` or  `onkeydown`

Comment: @Phiter I didn't know how to go about detecting the text changes, so no

Comment: @Sphinx I see, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you, use keyup event to get entered value

```
 $("#inputBox").on("keyup", function(){
      if($(this).val() == "abc")
         $(this).val("123");
    })
```

Comment: Ideally, some explanation would be given.

Comment: @Devaffair correct i have added short explanation to use keyup event to get entered value

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="inputBox" type="text">
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#inputBox', function(){
$(this).val("Your new value");
return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0ug8y3e/

There is a 'change' event on jQuery, but it's only called when the input has lost it's focus, so using a keydown, keypressed or keyup is better.

Comment: This answer is much more elaborated.  please just change $("#inputBox") to $(this) and it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#inputBox" ).keyup(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "abc") {
        $(this).val("123");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the full solution, it will convert each letter to its numerical value as you type:

```
const input = $('#inputBox');
input.keyup(event => {
    input.val(processContents(input.val()));
});
function processContents(value) {
    let contents = value.split('');
    contents.forEach((char, index) => {
        var charPos = char.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
        console.log(charPos);
        if (charPos >= 97 && charPos <= 122) {
            contents[index] = charPos - 96;
        }
    });
    return contents.join('');
}
```